# Codeigniter dropbox api

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, curl, dropbox

I tried to make upload in codeigniter with jimdoescode library but I got this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 8192
>
> Message: curl_setopt(): The usage of the @filename API for file uploading is deprecated. Please use the CURLFile class instead
>
> Filename: libraries/Dropbox.php
>
> Line Number: 493

Code in library for cURL is:

```
private function _connect($url, $header, $request, $postdata = false, $destination = false)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ) ;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1); // Require TLS
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, __DIR__."/certs/trusted-certs.crt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH, __DIR__."/certs/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $request);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, explode(self::LINE_END, $header));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

    if(is_array($postdata))
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    }
    
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    
    if(self::DEBUG)
    {
        error_log(print_r(curl_getinfo($ch), true));
        error_log($response);
    }
    
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    
    //If this is a content request write the file
    if($destination !== false)
    {
        //If the response was good then write
        //the file and return true
        if($code == '200')
        {
            $fh = fopen($destination, 'w');
            fwrite($fh, $response);
            if($fh !== false)
            {
                fclose($fh);
                return true;
            }
        }
        //The response was bad or the file couldn't
        //be written so return false.
        return false;
    }
    else return $response;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this, cause I am not familiar with this.

Comment: You're running into PHP 5.6 disabling file uploads by prefixing a path with `@` and instead needing to use a [`CURLFile`](http://php.net/curlfile) object.  The easy hack is to add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);` to the code to allow it.  Otherwise see the CURLFile docs for how to construct an object safe for uploading in PHP 5.5+.

Comment: I tried to disable but I got same error. When I write 'true' for safe upload I get : stdClass Object ( [error] => stdClass Object ( [file] => Expecting a file upload ) ) . I tried to understand how to make CURLFile but I can't got it.